# Inno Setup: How to change the font color of a TNewRadioButton?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

In Inno Setup I have a TNewRadioButton.

```
FullRadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
```

And it has the following Caption:

```
FullRadioButton.Caption := 'New Customer';
```

But the color of the text is black by default.
I am trying to change its color the following way but it doesn't work:

```
FullRadioButton.Font.Color := $FF0000;// doesn't work
FullRadioButton.Color := $FF0000// doesn't work
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Here is my full source code if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/uj3sxvkq/

Comment: You're out of luck here (not completely, but it's quite a lot of pain to subclass a control in Inno Setup). But you can workaround this by creating a radio button with empty caption and put a static text control by the radio.

Comment: what do you mean by "subclass a control"?

Comment: Intercept the control's window proc. Then you would need to paint the text over the text rendered by the system in the response to the `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: Then what does TNewRadioButton's Color property do? TRadioButton = class(TButtonControl)
  property Color: TColor; read write;
end;
TFont = class(TGraphicsObject)
  property Color: Integer; read write;
end;

Comment: Very, briefly. Blame Delphi for that. That radio button is the OS' own, the system renders it. Even though Delphi publishes the `Font.Color` property, it doesn't  render the control's text with this color. It lets only the system draw the control which uses its own default font color for the control (as defined by theme).

Comment: I intercepted the control's window proc like you said and now it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the full code to change the color of the radio button?