# How to change the radio button color in the LicensePage?

Tags: colors, radio-button, inno-setup, wndproc

How to change the radio button color in the LicensePage?

The following code does not work:

```
with WizardForm do
  begin
     LicenseAcceptedRadio.Font.Color := clWhite;
  end;
```

It would seem that the Inno Setup does not change the color of some controls.

I assume you need to use the WindowProc functions from the DLL file [InnoCallback](https://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=55) in order to set the colors. But what is the code for it?

Some references:

**[Inno Setup: How to change the font color of a TNewRadioButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206904/inno-setup-how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-tnewradiobutton)**

[Change the entire font style of all dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076216/change-the-entire-font-style-of-all-dialogs)

[Inno Setup Licence Agreement Font Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968442/inno-setup-licence-agreement-font-color)

https://documentation.help/Inno-Setup/topic_scriptclasses.htm

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag. InnoSetup uses PascalScript, which is *not* Delphi, so unless you're working on the source code of InnoSetup itself and not an install script, the Delphi tag does not apply.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me.

Comment: If that didn't work, you should edit your question with more details and explain what you did, what failed,etc.

Comment: As I explained in the question, it would seem that the Inno Setup does not change the color of some controls. Radio Button color does not change even if you change it using the code in the above question. This could be possible by using WindowProc.

Comment: The answer to *"How to change the radio button color in the LicensePage?"* is *"subclass the control"* or *"create a radio button with no caption and use a label together with it"*. If you already know that, then I do not think your question title summarizes your question correctly.

Comment: The idea, "_create a radio button with no caption and use a label together with it_" is a good one. Thanks. If you add an answer to this question with "radio button without caption", then I'll select your answer.

Comment: That's already suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29968442/850848